# Automatically pass value disjoint into their table

Tags: sql, apex, oracle

I have table disjoint cash and debit card from table payment . So the situantion is when I key in the table payment  , I want data cash and debit from table payment going automatically into their table . Can someone explain to me how to do it ? I really need help

I want data cash and debit from table payment going automatically into their table

Comment: Hi - please update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve; all as editable text formatted as tables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.